# How to connect raspi peripherals at a distance?

Tags: pi-zero, peripherals, cable

I would like to connect a few peripherals to my Raspi GPIO such as a access control keypad and ipcams. I know IPcams can run many meters on LAN cables but what is recommended for a peripheral such as the keypad which works fine on the (+-20cm) standard jumper cables? I expect the keypad to be about 3m away. Would it be better to attach the keypad to a raspi zero and the zero to the raspi via another cable? Whatever is recommended what would be the max distance possible?

Thanks a lot,

Josh

Comment: Simplest for a keyboard is a long USB cable...  Second would be Bluetooth - keyboards and Raspberry PI OS are normally  compatible. Other things depend totally on the device so I'm voting for close.  If you need advice on specific sensors then please add more details to your question and I can retract my vote.

Comment: Hi, thanks I meant keypad (not key board) connected via gpio cables like such https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/connecz-raspberry-pi-kecpad-code-lock/

Comment: Best to ask on the electronics forum as that keypad needs to be scanned to ID the key presses and you run into electronic issues rather than Pi.